# How can I nest coordinate calculations in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations

Why does this not work? I'm not using LaTeX and TikZ very much; I don't see it.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (Zero)  at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=below:cell a] (vertexA) at (0, 10);
\coordinate[label={above right:cell b}, label={below right:cell c}] 
           (vertexB) at (5, 8);
\coordinate(vertexC) at (2.5, 0);
\coordinate(vertexD) at (12, 4);

\coordinate (centroidCellA) at  ($ 1/3*((vertexA)+(vertexB)+(vertexC)) $);       
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I get

```
! Package pgf Error: No shape named (vertexA is known.
```

Comment: I tried the code in QTikZ and is OK, something must be wrong with your pgf installation.

Comment: That code snippet compiles without errors in my system after suitable completion. Please post the complete version (including `\documentclass`, relevant packages used, etc.) of the problematic code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The syntax for coordinate calculations is

```
<factor>*<coordinate><modifiers>
```

The problem is that `(vertexA)+(vertexB)+(vertexC)` is not a coordinate.  You have to tell `tikz` that you want it to calculate the coordinate at `(vertexA)+(vertexB)+(vertexC)`.  This will work:

```
\coordinate (centroidCellA) at  ($ 1/3*($(vertexA)+(vertexB)+(vertexC)$) $);
```

(You can nest coordinate calculations).

Comment: Funny, I tried `($ 1/3*({(vertexA)+(vertexB)+(vertexC)}) $)` which doesn't work, while I thought it should. And I was under the impression that you can't nest coordinate calculations (without hiding the inner one in `{ }`). I have to check how TikZ does the parsing in this case...

Comment: "The problem is that (vertexA)+(vertexB)+(vertexC) is not a coordinate." How should anybody see this? vector + vector == vector!

Comment: {} is for factors, right?

Comment: @Nils: The `{}` avoids that the TeX parser is taking the included `)` as end of the first `(`. The same is needed if you have `[]` inside an optional argument. However, it doesn't work here as I thought.

Comment: @Nils: I know that and you know that, but does `tikz` know that?

Comment: @Nils: On a serious note, nowhere in the `pgf/tikz` manual does it say that you can specify a coordinate as `(x1,y1) + (x2,y2)`.  It does say, though, that you can use coordinate calculations and specify it as `($ (x1,y1) + (x2,y2) $)`.

Answer (score 5):

Jan's answer is perfect. Another possibility is

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate(vertexA) at (0, 10);
  \coordinate (vertexB) at (5, 8);
  \coordinate(vertexC) at (2.5, 0);

  %\coordinate (centroidCellA) at  ($ 1/3*($(vertexA)+(vertexB)+(vertexC)$) $);
  \coordinate (centroidCellA) at (barycentric cs:vertexA=1 ,vertexB=1,vertexC=1); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```